# Chrome refuses to set SVG filter from data uri

Tags: google-chrome, data-uri, svg-filters

I'm trying to make a bookmarklet that will set an SVG filter over the entire page it is loaded into. To that end, it sets a style on the root element:

```
document.children[0].style.filter='url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4…#h)';
```

This works well in Firefox, but Chrome seems to think that it is unsafe cross-site content, drops the filter, and outputs a warning to the console:

[image: Unsafe attempt to load URL data:… from frame with URL http:… Domains, protocols and ports must match.]
<sub>(source: [codl.fr](http://f.codl.fr/1402/0Axcp0.png))</sub>

Is this expected behaviour? I would like to be sure before I file a bug. If so, how else can I acheve this?

Here is a test page containing the bookmarklet: http://f.codl.fr/1402/hacker/

Comment: Another demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzpaJb - I think it's a bug in Chrome/Webkit. If you add `<svg>` element in the HTML source and use `id='h'` there, you'll probably find that your above url suddenly refers to element in HTML source (that is, "#h" in the end of your URL somehow refers to HTML element, not element defined by the data URL).